# How to set time to a date object in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I created a `Date` object in Java. When I do so, it shows something like: `date=Tue Aug 09 00:00:00 IST 2011`. As a result, it appears that my Excel file is lesser by one day (27 feb becomes 26 feb and so on) I think it must be because of time. How can I set it to something like 5:30 pm?

Comment: Related: [Java Date cut off time information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908387/java-date-cut-off-time-information)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

Date d = cal.getTime();
```

Also See

- [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)
- [Calendar doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer . I have posted the link below.

Comment: Is is means ( date 17:30:0:0 )  ?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 23):

Can you show code which you use for setting date object? Anyway< you can use this code for intialisation of date:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2011-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Comment: DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(st[length]);

System.out.print("date="+date);
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
date = cal.getTime();
System.out.print("date="+date);

Comment: I am setting the time 5:30 pm.

Answer (score 7):

I should like to contribute the modern answer. This involves using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, and not the old `Date` nor `Calendar` except where there’s no way to avoid it.

Your issue is very likely really a timezone issue. When it is Tue Aug 09 00:00:00 IST 2011, in time zones west of IST midnight has not yet been reached. It is still Aug 8. If for example your API for putting the date into Excel expects UTC, the date will be the day before the one you intended. I believe the real and good solution is to produce a date-time of 00:00 UTC (or whatever time zone or offset is expected and used at the other end).

```
    LocalDate yourDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 27);
    ZonedDateTime utcDateDime = yourDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(utcDateDime);
```

This prints

```
2018-02-27T00:00Z
```

`Z` means UTC (think of it as offset zero from UTC or Zulu time zone). Better still, of course, if you could pass the `LocalDate` from the first code line to Excel. It doesn’t include time-of-day, so there is no confusion possible. On the other hand, if you need an old-fashioned `Date` object for that, convert just before handing the `Date` on:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(utcDateDime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

On my computer this prints

```
Tue Feb 27 01:00:00 CET 2018
```

Don’t be fooled, it is correct. My time zone (Central European Time) is at offset +01:00 from UTC in February (standard time), so 01:00:00 here is equal to 00:00:00 UTC. It’s just `Date.toString()` grabbing the JVMs time zone and using it for producing the string.

> How can I set it to something like 5:30 pm?

To answer your direct question directly, if you have a `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`, in all of these cases the following will accomplish what you asked for:

```
    yourDateTime = yourDateTime.with(LocalTime.of(17, 30));
```

If `yourDateTime` was a `LocalDateTime` of `2018-02-27T00:00`, it will now be `2018-02-27T17:30`. Similarly for the other types, only they include offset and time zone too as appropriate.

If you only had a date, as in the first snippet above, you can also add time-of-day information to it:

```
    LocalDate yourDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 27);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = yourDate.atTime(LocalTime.of(17, 30));
```

For most purposes you should prefer to add the time-of-day in a specific time zone, though, for example

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = yourDate.atTime(LocalTime.of(17, 30))
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

This yields `2018-02-27T17:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]`.

### `Date` and `Calendar` vs `java.time`

The `Date` class that you use as well as `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` used in the other answers are long outdated, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular has proven troublesome. In all cases the modern Java date and time API is so much nicer to work with. Which is why I wanted to provide this answer to an old question that is still being visited.

**Link:** [Oracle Tutorial Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to java 8 and the [API java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), here is my simple function to copy the time of one date to another date using the old java.util.Calendar (inspire by Jigar Joshi) :

```
/**
 * Copy only the time of one date to the date of another date.
 */
public static Date copyTimeToDate(Date date, Date time) {
    Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    t.setTime(time);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, t.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, t.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, t.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, t.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Calendar calendar = new Calendar.Builder()
                .setDate(2022, Calendar.JUNE, 1)
                .setTimeOfDay(0, 0, 0)
                .build();

System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.