# How to add current time to a previous date in java?

Tags: java, date

I was trying to add current time into previous date. But it was adding in current date with time not with previous date.

see my bellow code:

```
Date startUserDate = ;//this is my previous date object;
startUserDate.setTime(new Date().getTime());// here i'm trying to add current time in previous date.
System.out.println("current time with previous Date :"+startUserDate);
```

In previous date there is no time and i want to add current time in previous date.I can do this, please help me out.

Comment: You can do it using `DateFormat` and `substring()`,  take a look at my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set time to a date object in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165428/how-to-set-time-to-a-date-object-in-java)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use calendar object

Get instance of calendar object and set your past time to it
        Date startUserDate = ;

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.settime(startUserDate);
```

Create new calendar instance

```
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.settime(new Date());
```

format the date to get string representation of time of current date

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String currentdate =  sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

split that string to get hour minute and second object

```
                String hh = expiry.split(":")[0];
                String mm = expiry.split(":")[1];
                String ss = expiry.split(":")[2];
```

add it to the previous calendar object

```
    calendar .add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hh);
    calendar .add(Calendar.MINUTE, mm);
    calendar .add(Calendar.SECOND, ss);
```

this date will have current time added to your date

```
   Date newDate = calendar.getTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `DateFormat` and `String`, here's the solution that you need:

**Code:**

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String timeString = df.format(new Date()).substring(10); // 10 is the beginIndex of time here

DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String startUserDateString = df2.format(startUserDate);

startUserDateString = startUserDateString+" "+timeString;
// you will get this format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" 

//then parse the new date here
startUserDate = df.parse(startUserDateString);
```

**Explanation:**

Just convert the current date to a string and then extract the time from it using `.substring()` method, then convert your userDate to a string concatenate the taken time String to it and finally parse this date to get what you need.

**Example:**

> You can see it working in this **[ideone DEMO](https://ideone.com/cS6xK6)**.
>
> Which takes `02/20/2002` in input and returns `02/20/2002 04:36:14` as result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar`:

- first set the date/time of the first calendar object to the old date
- object use as second Calendar object to set the current time on the
- first calendar object then convert it back to date

as follow:

```
//E.g. for startUserDate 
Date startUserDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L) - (60L * 60L * 1000L));//minus 1 day and 1 hour
Calendar calDateThen = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calTimeNow = Calendar.getInstance();
calDateThen.setTime(startUserDate);
calDateThen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calTimeNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calDateThen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calTimeNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
calDateThen.set(Calendar.SECOND, calTimeNow.get(Calendar.SECOND));
startUserDate = calDateThen.getTime();
System.out.println(startUserDate);
```

The second Calendar object `calTimeNow` can be replaced with `Calendar.getInstance()` where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        
    LocalDate somePreviousDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.NOVEMBER, 22);
    
    LocalTime timeOfDayNow = LocalTime.now(zone);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = somePreviousDate.atTime(timeOfDayNow);
    
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

When I ran the code just now — 16:25 in my time zone — I got this output:

> 2018-11-22T16:25:53.253892

If you’ve got an old-fashioned `Date` object, start by converting to a modern `Instant` and perform further conversion from there:

```
    Date somePreviousDate = new Date(1_555_555_555_555L);
    LocalDate date = somePreviousDate.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
    
    LocalTime timeOfDayNow = LocalTime.now(zone);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(timeOfDayNow);
```

> 2019-04-18T16:25:53.277947

If conversely you need the result as an old-fashioned `Date`, also convert over `Instant`:

```
    Instant i = dateTime.atZone(zone).toInstant();
    Date oldfasionedDate = Date.from(i);
    
    System.out.println(oldfasionedDate);
```

> Thu Nov 22 16:25:53 CET 2018

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: I strongly recommend this answer. The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `getTime` method returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 so to get the `time` portion of the date you can either use a Calendar object or simply use modula arithmetic (using the above milliseconds value and the MAX millseconds in a day) to extract the time portion of the Date.

Then when you have the time you need to add it to the second date,

but seriously, use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

and use things like `get (HOUR)` and `get (MINUTE)` etc. which then you can use with `set (HOUR, val)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Calendar` class to perform addition to `Date`object. Date's `setTime()` will set that time in `Date` object but not add i.e it will overwrite previous date. `new Date().getTime()` will not return only time portion but time since Epoch. Also, how did you manipulated , `startUserDate`  to not have any time (I mean , was it via Calendar or Formatter) ? 
See Answer , [Time Portion of Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363307/getting-the-time-component-of-a-java-date-or-calendar) to calculate only time portion,

> long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
>   Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
>   long timePortion = now.getTime() % MILLIS_PER_DAY;

then you can use something like, `cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int)timePortion);` where cal is Calendar object corresponding to your `startUserDate` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(startUserDate );

```
    //new date for current time
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String currentdate =  sdf.format(new Date());
    String hhStr = currentdate.split(":")[0];
    String mmStr = currentdate.split(":")[1];
    String ssStr = currentdate.split(":")[2];
    Integer hh = 0;
    Integer mm = 0;
    Integer ss = 0;
    try {
        hh = Integer.parseInt(hhStr);
        mm = Integer.parseInt(mmStr);
        ss = Integer.parseInt(ssStr);
    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hh);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mm);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, ss);

    startUserDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: That’s about as complicated as it can get. Also I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).