# Date.toString() - sql vs util dates

Tags: java, date, jdbc, simpledateformat

I need to remove time from a `Date` Object. Here is my try,

**Code:**

```
System.out.println("date " + dbDate);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println("formatter.format(dbDate) " + formatter.format(dbDate));
System.out.println("final " + formatter.parse(formatter.format(dbDate)));
```

**Output:**

```
date 2011-12-03 23:59:59.0
formatter.format(dbDate) 2011-12-03
final Sat Dec 03 00:00:00 IST 2011
```

I want to the final date to display in `2011-12-03`. But after conversion `toString()` of that `Date` is in different format. I am missing something. Please help.

**Update:**

In my application, I have two different methods to get `dbDate`. `EXPIRY_DATE` column is type of `DATE`.

First query uses `dbDate = (java.util.Date) rs.getDate("EXPIRY_DATE");`.

For this `dbDate`, `System.out.println("date " + dbDate);` gives `date 2011-12-03`

Second query uses `dbDate = rs.getTimestamp("EXPIRY_DATE");`

For this `dbDate`, `System.out.println("date " + dbDate);` gives `date 2011-12-03 23:59:59.0`.

This is my problem. As I thought `toString()` was giving problem, I didn't mention the full problem.

**Solution:**

I did not have choices to avoid `java.sql.Date` as my application methods have multiple usages.
I tried the below and worked,

```
dbDate = new java.sql.Date(dbDate.getTime());
```

Comment: I had to use java.sql.Timestamp to also get the time. Thanks for providing the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I need to remove time from a Date Object*

You can't. The [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object contains both the date and time. Its `toString()` is also in [a fixed format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29). If you want to represent it without time to humans, then you need to convert it to a `String` like as you already did. Or, if you intend to store it in the DB without the time (as the `db` part in the variable name `dbDate` suggests), then you need to convert it to [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dbDate.getTime()));
// ...
```

---

**Update** as per your update, the `ResultSet#getDate()` returns an instance of `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date` (but it is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, that's why the unnecessary cast worked; please note that casting is not the same as converting, a real conversion would be `new java.util.Date(dbDate.getTime())`). As you can read in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString%28%29) of the `toString()` method of `java.sql.Date`, it's indeed in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

So, your concrete problem is that you're confusing `java.sql.Date` with `java.util.Date` and that you're misgrasping the internal workings of `java.util.Date` and been mislead by the `toString()` method. Everything is working as intented.

#### Related:

- [Handling MySQL datetimes and timestamps in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323618/handling-mysql-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-java/3323870#3323870)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable information Balus. But I can't change those `rs.get`s as they are existing methods which has been used in lot of places. So I am checking `util` to `sql` date conversions.

Comment: Using `java.sql` in model is however a bad practice. I do not understand why you're worrying about the time part in the date. Whenever you want to represent the date to the humans, just convert it to `String` **in the desired format** using `SimpleDateFormat`. That's exactly where it is for. You should never use `toString()` to represent dates to humans.

Comment: I understand. But I am not giving to UI. I need to send this to a Webservice method, where am not allowed to change, like formatting and setting. That's why am trying this.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is remove the time part of the `Date` object:

- Use a `Calendar` to remove the time part of your `Date` object. As pointed out in this question: [Java Date cut off time information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1908387/851811).

If you only want to obtain a `String` representation without the time part of the `Date` object:

- You've got to use `SimpleDateFormat.format()`. You can't make `Date.toString()` return a different value, it will always use that pattern. Look at its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.toString%28%29).

Comment: But the above format and parse removed time, I think. My only problem is the `toString ()` part. But the information about `toString()` part is useful. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, formatting and parsing is also a correct way of removing time. I stil fail to see why do you want to use `Date.toString()` if you've already got it in the desired format. To achieve this you could always subclass `Date`, and override `toString()` to use a given format.

Answer (score 0):

When you last call `formatter.parse()` you get back a `Date` object; the concatenation then makes an implicit call to `Date.toString()`: the format returned by this call is the default for the locale set in the JVM.
What you must understand is that the `Date` object has no knowledge of the string representation, internally it's just an aggregate of inte

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem for those who encounters the same problem as mine I write this entry:

The problem is the date value that is taken from database and passed to the web client is in format `yyyy-mm-dd` but in the application for the first entry there is not database value so we create date object and passed the value to web client which gives us timestamp value. The value that will be passed to web client must be in date format so `SimpleDateFormat` is not a good choice for me
So from this post ı understand the difference of `java.sql.date` and java.util.date and then create first object as

```
Date date = new java.sql.Date(1430454600000L);
```

which gives `yyyy-mm-dd` value for `toString` method.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The [Answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242880/642706) is correct: You cannot eliminate a time-of-day from a class object defined to hold a date plus a time-of-day.

Also, you are using troublesome old classes (`java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`) that are now obsolete, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Instead, use a date-only class for a date-only value. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. The `java.sql.Date` *pretends* to do the same, but actually does carry a time of day due to very poor design decision of inheriting from `java.util.Date`. Avoid `java.sql.Date`, and use only `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

You are starting with a `java.util.Date` object apparently. That represents a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution in milliseconds. So using that to determine a date requires a time zone. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

To get a date-only value from your `java.util.Date`, first convert to its *java.time* replacement, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). To convert back and forth, call new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

That value is in UTC by definition. Apply your desired time zone (`ZoneId`) to generate a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Finally, extract your desired `LocalDate` object from `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* classes with your database. So no need to use the the `java.sql` classes such as `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).