# First day of current year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below query in a postgresql database

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
where insertdate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So how can I replace the `'2012-01-01'` asking for the first day of the current year

There is one more issue. When I m having a new record in the account table the same moment is running the above select so it doesnt bring me the record I have just made.Is it reasonable?
What is the best way to overtake it?

Comment: 'YYYY-01-01' is always the first day of a year...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're looking for [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), which can truncate a date to a specified precision (e.g. `year`, `month`, `day`):

```
SELECT date_trunc('year', now());
```

In your query:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts where insertdate BETWEEN 
date_trunc('year', now()) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: It was perfect but I am having one more problem.
When I m having a new record in the account table the same moment is running the above select so it doesnt bring me the record I have just made...What is the best way to overtake it?

Comment: If the operations are occurring in separate transactions, the query should find the new record as soon as the inserting transaction is committed. If they're in the same transaction, you just have to run the queries in the correct order.

Comment: is there a way to add 'current day 23:59:59' ?
something like '2012-6-19 23:59:59'

Comment: I am ussing play framework play.db.jpa.GenericModel.JPAQuery and I am not sure what is happening behinde the code

Comment: Why are you writing a postgres query if you're going to issue it with JPA? You can pass a `Date` with the time field set as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1908419/320220)

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use  this CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.YEAR-01-01