# Set time to 00:00:00

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I have a problem resetting hours in Java. For a given date I want to set the hours to 00:00:00.

This is my code :

```
/**
     * Resets milliseconds, seconds, minutes and hours from the provided date
     *
     * @param date
     * @return
     */
    public static Date trim(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes the time is `12:00:00` and sometimes it is `00:00:00` and when I query the database for an entity that was saved on `07.02.2013 00:00:00` and the actual entity time, that is stored, is `12:00:00` the query fails.

I know that `12:00:00 == 00:00:00`!

I am using AppEngine. Is this an appengine bug, problem or some other issue?  Or does it depend on something else?

Comment: Could this have something to do with different locales or does this happen from the same PC all the time?

Comment: it happens when I deploy on appengine.

Comment: Lots of other solutions for cutting off time: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1908955/2646526

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I used `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);`, for my purpose, it works well.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Use another constant instead of `Calendar.HOUR`, use [`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY).

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
```

`Calendar.HOUR` uses 0-11 (for use with AM/PM), and `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` uses 0-23.

To quote the Javadocs:

> public static final int HOUR
>
> Field number for get and set indicating
>   the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour
>   clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12.
>   E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.

and

> public static final int HOUR_OF_DAY
>
> Field number for get and set
>   indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour
>   clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

Testing ("now" is currently c. 14:55 on July 23, 2013 Pacific Daylight Time):

```
public class Main
{
   static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(now.getTime()));
        now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(now.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
2013-07-23 12:00:00
2013-07-23 00:00:00
```

Comment: @JarrodRoberson But using `Calendar.HOUR` wouldn't set PM to AM, leaving it as 12:00 noon.

Comment: Can you please help me in constructing a LocalDate with hours, minute and second? I know one option is to follow DateTime.

Comment: Whoever created the field HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY should have been flogged and put on rations.

Comment: @AndroidDev whoever invented am/pm deserves the same... This also goes for non-metric standards

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: All is correct, but there should be millis also: now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Comment: You can set Minutes and Seconds  too . Say for example : 

calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 46);

Answer (score 43):

## java.time

Using the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); # 2015-11-19T19:42:19.224
# start of a day
now.with(LocalTime.MIN); # 2015-11-19T00:00
now.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT); # 2015-11-19T00:00
```

If you do not need time-of-day (hour, minute, second etc. parts) consider using [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) class.

```
LocalDate.now(); # 2015-11-19
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer since Java 1.8 has been released since this question was first asked.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the **wrong class** to use for this. It cannot represent a moment as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Calling `LocalDateTime.now` almost never makes sense. Use `ZonedDateTime` instead. Otherwise you are ignoring crucial time zone issues. For one thing, some dates in some zones do *not* start at 00:00!

Answer (score 15):

Here are couple of utility functions I use to do just this.

```
/**
 * sets all the time related fields to ZERO!
 *
 * @param date
 *
 * @return Date with hours, minutes, seconds and ms set to ZERO!
 */
public static Date zeroTime( final Date date )
{
    return DateTimeUtil.setTime( date, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}

/**
 * Set the time of the given Date
 *
 * @param date
 * @param hourOfDay
 * @param minute
 * @param second
 * @param ms
 *
 * @return new instance of java.util.Date with the time set
 */
public static Date setTime( final Date date, final int hourOfDay, final int minute, final int second, final int ms )
{
    final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime( date );
    gc.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay );
    gc.set( Calendar.MINUTE, minute );
    gc.set( Calendar.SECOND, second );
    gc.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, ms );
    return gc.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

One more JAVA 8 way:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

But it's a lot more useful to edit the date that already exists.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment, as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Calling `LocalDateTime.now` almost never makes sense. You should be using `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 6):

See the below code:

```
    String datePattern24Hrs = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    String datePattern12Hrs = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat24Hrs = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern24Hrs);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat12Hrs = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern12Hrs);

    Date dateNow = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dateNow);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Date dateTime = calendar.getTime();

    String dateTimeIn24Hrs = simpleDateFormat24Hrs.format(dateTime);
    String dateTimeIn12Hrs = simpleDateFormat12Hrs.format(dateTime);

    System.out.println("DateTime in 24Hrs: ".concat(dateTimeIn24Hrs));
    System.out.println("DateTime in 12Hrs: ".concat(dateTimeIn12Hrs));
```

The expected output is as below:

- DateTime in 24Hrs: 2021-06-29 00:00:00
- DateTime in 12Hrs: 2021-06-29 12:00:00

I hope it helps with the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You would better to primarily set time zone to the DateFormat component like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Then you can get "00:00:00" time by passing 0 milliseconds to formatter:

```
String time = dateFormat.format(0);
```

or you can create Date object:

```
Date date = new Date(0); // also pass milliseconds
String time = dateFormat.foramt(date);
```

or you be able to have more possibilities using Calendar component but you should also set timezone as GMT to calendar instance:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.US);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 37);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 27);

dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

As Java8 add new Date functions, we can do this easily.

```java
    // If you have instant, then:
    Instant instant1 = Instant.now();
    Instant day1 = instant1.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(day1); //2019-01-14T00:00:00Z

    // If you have Date, then:
    Date date = new Date();
    Instant instant2 = date.toInstant();
    Instant day2 = instant2.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(day2); //2019-01-14T00:00:00Z

    // If you have LocalDateTime, then:
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime day3 = dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(day3); //2019-01-14T00:00
    String format = day3.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(format);//2019-01-14T00:00:00
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment, as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Calling `LocalDateTime.now` almost never makes sense. You should be using `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate                                 // The terrible `java.util.Date` class is now legacy. Use *java.time* instead.
.toInstant()                                   // Convert this moment in UTC from the legacy class `Date` to the modern class `Instant`.
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )         // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
.toLocalDate()                                 // Extract the date-only portion.
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )   // Determine the first moment of that date in that zone. The day does *not* always start at 00:00:00.
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `Date` ➙ `Instant`

A `java.util.Date` represent a moment in UTC. Its replacement is `Instant`. Call the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

## Time zone

Specify the time zone in which you want your new time-of-day to make sense.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Apply the `ZoneId` to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Changing time-of-day

You asked to change the time-of-day. Apply a `LocalTime` to change all the time-of-day parts: hour, minute, second, fractional second. A new `ZonedDateTime` is instantiated, with values based on the original. The *java.time* classes use this [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern to provide [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;  // 3:30 PM.
ZonedDateTime zdtAtThreeThirty = zdt.with( lt ) ;
```

## First moment of day

But you asked specifically for 00:00. So apparently you want the first moment of the day. Beware: some days in some zones do not start at 00:00:00. They may start at another time such as 01:00:00 because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Let *java.time* determine the first moment. Extract the date-only portion. Then pass the time zone to get first moment.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
ZonedDateTime zdtFirstMomentOfDay = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Adjust to UTC

If you need to go back to UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdtFirstMomentOfDay.toInstant() ;
```

## `Instant` ➙ `Date`

If you need a `java.util.Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Before Java 8:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

After Java 8:

```
LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way,

```
final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.setTime(new Date());
        today.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        today.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
        today.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        today.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        today.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this could be easier (In Java 8)

```
LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I worked with other stuff last 2 years, and Java 6/7 before it. I've back to Java now (after worked with few things on Groovy) and liking Java 8 differences.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use a DateFormat without any seconds:

```
public static Date trim(Date date) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date trimmed = null;
    try {
        trimmed = format.parse(format.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {} // will never happen
    return trimmed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this with the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, dayOfMonth, 0, 0, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need format 00:00:00 in string, you should use SimpleDateFormat as below. Using "H "instead "h".

```
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
//not SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Calendar calendarDM = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarDM.setTime(today);
calendarDM.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendarDM.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendarDM.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(calendarDM.getTime()));

//Result is: Current Date: 29-10-2018 00:00:00
```