# Calendar can not set hour correctly

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

When I want to get a time set to 00:00:00, Calendar always get 12:00:00

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
// even set AM_PM it was still 12:00:00
// currentDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
// Calendar.HOUR still not work
currentDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
currentDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
currentDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
currentDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

How could I make it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821601/set-time-to-000000

Comment: @Sanjeev that's what i want. thanks

Comment: @Sanjeev that's not work. I add some pics to show you that

Answer (score 3):

But when is 00:00:00, really, when you get down to it? Is it today? Or yesterday?

To eliminate confusion, try something like

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
// even set AM_PM it was still 12:00:00
// currentDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
// Calendar.HOUR still not work
currentDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
currentDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
currentDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
currentDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: It's so strange that I syserr the date, it was 00:00:00 on the console. But I make a breakpoints to the line, then watch the date, it's 12:00:00.  I'll paste a picture to you latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can set hour like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 4, 15, 0, 0, 0);

System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2014 mai 15 00:00:00
```

`mai` means `may` month in french.

Comment: The result output in console is 00:00:00. But when I set a breakpoints to watch the value it was 12:00:00. You can see it in the picture above. Or is it just a bug in eclipse?