# Convert integer to datetime java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have an integer value with following.How can I convert integer to Datetime?

int input DateTime=1 6 25;

convert input to output

int output DateTime=1:06:25;

Comment: How is `DateTime` defined & what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 8:

```
java.time.LocalTime time = java.time.LocalTime.of(hour, minute, second);
```

Comment: So How can I set value without Localtime?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821601/set-time-to-000000/17821620#17821620