# Convert milliseconds to Date in specific format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Using below code , the output is **15-Mar-2016 06:24:41.296PM**

```
Date sDate=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat pattern = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSSa");
System.out.println(pattern .format(sDate));
```

If I want the output as **15-Mar-2016 06:00:00.0PM** is it possible?

Comment: You may want to first reset the mm:ss.SSS part of your `Date` ,  see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821601/set-time-to-000000

Comment: instead of doing a `new Date()` get a `Calendar` instance and set the mins and secs to 0.

Comment: So actually you want to round your date to hour resolution? What if the time is 5.59.59 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `Calendar` and resetting portions of the date to zero, you can use single quotes to insert literal strings in the formatted date:

```
SimpleDateFormat pattern = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:'00:00.0'a");
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/S78vSN)</kbd>

Comment: To avoid any confusion, you could precise in your answer that the date in itself won't be changed, only the visual representation given by the formatter will be altered.

Comment: @Spotted I am not sure where the confusion is - `SimpleDateFormat` never changes the date it is passed.

Comment: I thought it could be confusing if you examine the output of this program: `Date d = new Date(); SimpleDateFormat pattern = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:'00:00.0'a"); System.out.println(pattern.format(d)); System.out.println(d);` which give 2 different visual representations of the same object.

Comment: Why would you be using `SimpleDateFormat` in the first place if you found that `Date.toString()` met your requirements?

Comment: As a human, you could forget to use a `SimpleDateFormat` for a future use. Thus having a regression in your codebase because the generated representation doesn't match the expected one anymore.

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with whether the date is changed by using a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Could we continue the discussion on a chat ? I think I failed to express my opinion correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to **truncate** (i.e., floor) or **round** to the nearest hour, you could do one of the following:

```
    final long MS_PER_HOUR = 1000L * 60 * 60;
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSSa");

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long trunc = (now / MS_PER_HOUR) * MS_PER_HOUR;
    long round = ((now + MS_PER_HOUR / 2) / MS_PER_HOUR) * MS_PER_HOUR;

    System.out.println("now:   " + fmt.format(new Date(now)));
    System.out.println("trunc: " + fmt.format(new Date(trunc)));
    System.out.println("round: " + fmt.format(new Date(round)));
```

Which will generate this output for a time between 09:00:00 and 09:29:59

```
now:   15-Mar-2016 09:15:37.721AM
trunc: 15-Mar-2016 09:00:00.000AM
round: 15-Mar-2016 09:00:00.000AM
```

and, for a time between 09:30:00 and 09:59:59

```
now:   15-Mar-2016 09:45:50.925AM
trunc: 15-Mar-2016 09:00:00.000AM
round: 15-Mar-2016 10:00:00.000AM
```