# Is it possible to truncate date to Month with Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, truncate, java-time

I want to get the milliseconds truncated to days, I can use

```
Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli()
```

But I can't truncate to `ChronoUnit.MONTH` (it throws an exception). Do I need use [a Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1908419/3142888)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One way would be to manually set the day to the first of the month:

```
import static java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

ZonedDateTime truncatedToMonth = ZonedDateTime.now(UTC).truncatedTo(DAYS).withDayOfMonth(1);
System.out.println(truncatedToMonth); //prints 2015-06-01T00:00Z
long millis = truncatedToMonth.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
System.out.println(millis); // prints 1433116800000
```

Or an alternative with a `LocalDate`, which is maybe cleaner:

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = LocalDate.now(UTC).withDayOfMonth(1);
long millis = firstOfMonth.atStartOfDay(UTC).toEpochSecond() * 1000;
//or
long millis = firstOfMonth.atStartOfDay(UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Answer (score 47):

This is what [`java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) are for.

```
date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem of course in working with instants, then following code solved my problem:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(longTimestamp);
instant = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toInstant();
```

Answer (score -1):

For a simple way to do it:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
System.out.println(cal.getTime());

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());

cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());

cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());

cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

The output is:

```
Thu Jun 11 05:36:17 EDT 2015
Mon Jun 01 05:36:17 EDT 2015
Mon Jun 01 00:36:17 EDT 2015
Mon Jun 01 00:00:17 EDT 2015
Mon Jun 01 00:00:00 EDT 2015
Mon Jun 01 00:00:00 EDT 2015
```

Comment: Uh this not simple, in fact things like that were the whole reason of new Java 8 Dates API.

Comment: Interesting. This answer serves as a fine example of how java date manipulation code used to be written. And while perhaps looking rather straight-forward, it's not exactly elegant. So please read and learn from the other answers, and never write code like this again.