# Use a pattern matcher inside a getter method to format date/remove miliseconds

Tags: java

I am new to java.I am suppose to use pattern matcher inside getter method such that e.g: getCreatedTime() which actualy has miliseconds is removed via passing it to through pattern matcher inside getter.

```
RequestTO.getDetailsTO().setReqTimeStamp(automaticalyRecoveryTO.getCreatedTime());
```

Currently time format is in `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`  i.e. 26-SEP-18 04.29.48.452000000 PM   expected:- 26-SEP-18 04.29.48 PM without miliseconds or without writing a new function.Please help me with this.

Comment: `26-SEP-18 04.29.48.452000000 PM ` does not match the pattern `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`, so which is it?

Comment: `getCreatedDate()` returns `Date` (java.util.Date ???) ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908387/java-date-cut-off-time-information

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getCreatedTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date now = new Date();
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
    return strDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Currently time format is in YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Should have been YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

`26-SEP-18 04.29.48.452000000 PM` is the toString() of the old Date class in some English locale (PM means, the time is 16:29:48, HH=16).

To replace the milliseconds here:

```
String s = date.toString();
s = s.replaceFirst("(\\s\\d\\d.\\d\\d.\\d\\d)(\\d*)", "$1");
```

Here `.` stands for any char, also `.` itself; for other locales.