# Using Java Stream to count occurrences of Dates in a list of items

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of items with a (java.util.)Date property, and I want to create a DataSeriesItem **for each day** beginning from the oldest date up to now. It is for a chart series with a timeline.

The creation of that DataSeriesItem will look like this:
`DataSeriesItem seriesItem = new DataSeriesItem(Date, occurrenceCount);`
Where the `occurrenceCount` is the count of Items where their Date property matches that day. The first parameter can also be of type `java.time.Instant`

I have managed to find a way that works, but I am certain that my approach is *very* bad and could possibly be done with one stream, maybe two. However, I am a beginner in streams and could not do it with my knowledge.

**Is this possible with stream? How would it probably look like *approximately*?**
I'm not asking you to actually do my whole implementation anew, but only point me to the correct streamfunctions and mappings that you would use, and for bonus points an example of it.

Here is my ugly solution:

```
List<?> items = myItems;
Collection<Date> foundDates = new HashSet<>();

for (Object item : items) {
    foundDates.add((Date)getPropertyValueFromItem(item, configurator.getDateProperty()));
}

//======  This is the part I am asking about ======//

Map<Instant, Integer> foundInstants = new HashMap<>();
foundDates.stream().sorted(Date::compareTo).forEach(date -> {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.clear(); // clear nanoseconds, or else equals won't work!
    c.set(date.getYear()+1900, date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
    if(!foundInstants.containsKey(c.toInstant())){
        foundInstants.put(c.toInstant(), 1);
    } else {
        // increment count of that entry
        Integer value = foundInstants.get(c.toInstant());
        foundInstants.remove(c.toInstant());
        foundInstants.put(c.toInstant(), ++value);
    }
});

//====== Leaving this code here for context ======//  
// Could this maybe simplyfied too by using streams  ?

// find oldest date
Date dateIndex = foundDates.stream().min(Date::compareTo).get();
Date now = new Date();

// starting from oldest date, add a seriesItem for each day until now
// if dateOccurrences contains the current/iterated date, use it's value, else 0
while(dateIndex.before(now)){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.clear();// clear nanoseconds, or else equals won't work!
    c.set(dateIndex.getYear()+1900, dateIndex.getMonth(), dateIndex.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);

    if(foundInstants.containsKey(c.toInstant())){
        ExtendedDataSeriesItem seriesItem = new ExtendedDataSeriesItem(c.toInstant(), foundInstants.get(c.toInstant()));
        seriesItem.setSeriesType("singleDataPoint");
        series.add(seriesItem);
    } else {
        ExtendedDataSeriesItem seriesItem = new ExtendedDataSeriesItem(c.toInstant(), 0);
        seriesItem.setSeriesType("singleDataPoint");
        series.add(seriesItem);
    }
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // adding a day is complicated. Calendar gets it right. Date does not. This is why I don't use Date here
    dateIndex = c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `java.util.Date` whey you're obviously on Java 8 which supports `java.time.LocalDate`?

Comment: @daniu I did not do the Model. Also, quite irrelevant for this question

Comment: what's `series` in your question?

Comment: @nullpointer it's a DataSeries (com.vaadin.flow.component.charts.model.DataSeries)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy()` and then use the downstream collector `counting()`.

```
Map<Date, Long> occurrances = dateList.stream().collect(
                  groupingBy(d -> yourTransformation(d), counting()));
```

It should be easy enough to create your `DataSeriesItem` objects from that map.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: Works like a charm (I had to write `Collectors.groupingBy` else it wouldn't recognize it). I used basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1908419/3441504) for `yourTransformation(d)` except converting it to Date at the end instead of long.

Comment: @Cashbee you can use a static import so you don't need the `Collectors.`. I do that because it's more readable, and do so in answers here as well.

Answer (score 5):

To count you're looking for something like:

```
Map<Instant, Long> foundInstants =  foundDates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Date::toInstant, Collectors.counting()));
```

to add to that you could cut short those `if..else` into :

```
ExtendedDataSeriesItem seriesItem = 
        new ExtendedDataSeriesItem(c.toInstant(), foundInstants.getOrDefault(c.toInstant(), 0L));
seriesItem.setSeriesType("singleDataPoint");
series.add(seriesItem);
```

and this goes by saying that you should at the same time look for migrating to `LocalDateTime` and refrain from using `Date`.

Comment: That looks very promising and seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I'll need time to test it. daniu was first with kind of the same answer so the tick goes to him. Thanks nevertheless! @Lino nullpointer is right :)

Comment: @Cashbee nevermind, additionally shortened your `if..else` as well

Comment: After this hell of a day trying to convert Date into Calendar into Instant just because Date cant do addDays(1), there is no way I keep using Date :)